# CSS relative position and absolute position

Tags: css

CSS beginner here trying to figure out this situation:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}

#container{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#header {
  background-color: #88b;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  left: 0;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  right: 0;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #88b;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='header'>
    <p> div-header </p>
  </div>
  <div id='green'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer pretium dui sit amet felis. Integer sit amet diam. Phasellus ultrices viverra velit.</p>
  </div>
    <div id='red'>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer pretium dui sit amet felis. Integer sit amet diam. Phasellus ultrices viverra velit.</p>
  </div>
  <div id='footer'>
    <p> div-footer </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I remove `position: relative` from the `footer` element. Both `green` and `red` will hover above `footer`. I read somewhere else that this is because when you set an element to `position: absolute`, it does not remain in the flow of the doc.

My question is, why adding `position: relative` to `footer` makes it appear above the absolute positioned elements (e.g `green` and `red`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#layers)

> Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order.

and

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in
>   back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most
>      negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, **non-positioned descendants**.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and **the positioned descendants with stack level 0**.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

When you position the footer, you bump it from layer 3 to layer 6, at which point it is rendered on top of the other positioned elements because it appears later in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for digging up the css2 spec, wow! I assume  `absolute positioned` elements fall on layer 4?

Comment: @Cheng — No, because they wouldn't be floating or non-positioned. Absolutely positioned elements are stacked in exactly the same way as relatively positioned elements: level 6 unless they have a z-index specified (in which case they would be 2 or 7 depending on the value of the z-index).

Comment: I see, so what you are saying is that `position:relative` bumped `footer` to level 6, which is the same level as `green` and `red`. Since `footer` also appears later in the DOM, thus, it is rendered on top. correct?

Answer (score 0):

There are some misinterpretation about “position:relative” positioning. The first thing is “relative to itself” and not any other element. 
Now if you use this attribute (position:relative), you must use some other positioning attribute like (top , left, right, bottom) etc, otherwise it will no effect on its positioning at all.
The second thing (which is your case) is by using “relative” positioning is its ability to use z-index on that element. So even if you don't set a z-index value, this element will now appear on top of any other statically (means no specific position mentioned) positioned element. The other thing that happened with this positioning is its limits the scope of absolutely positioned child elements. Any element that is a child of the relatively positioned element can be absolutely positioned within that block.
For further details you can Google it or can visit here
[Absolute positioning inside Relative positioning](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Comment: Could you point me to the source that states **a relative positioned element will appear on top of any other statically positioned elements?** Thanks.

Comment: I don't actually remember the source. But this is what I found when I Google about it:
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score -1):

Just give the `#green` and `#red` div :style

`z-index: 2;`...

this will solve ur problem

Comment: I didn't ask how to make  `green` and `red` to appear on top or `footer`, please read the last sentence of my question.